# How to customize PriorityQueue.stream().foreach to iterate in priority order

Tags: java, java-stream, priority-queue

I have a class with PriorityQueue field inside:

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    Queue<T> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

I want somehow get a stream from MyClass and use foreach and want the sequence behave in priority order of my PriorityQueue. The easiest way is to override stream() method:

```
@Override
public Stream stream() {
    return queue.stream();
}
```

but this will not expose the queue element in priority order. So the question is: how to make foreach stream method behave like:

```
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) 
        queue.poll();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`Stream::generate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) and [`Queue::poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html#poll--) method to get create a `Stream` with elements from `PriorityQueue`  with keeping their order:

```
@Override
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return Stream.generate(queue::poll);
}
```

However this might be dangerous because `Stream::generate` will be invoking `poll` constantly so it is potentially an inifinite Stream. Therfore using `Stream::limit` with the queue size should be considered :

```
@Override
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return Stream.generate(queue::poll)
        .limit(queue.size());
}
```

Or you could simply return sorted stream :

```
@Override
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return queue.stream()
            .sorted(comparator);
}
```

where comparator is your comparator.

In **Java 9** you could use [`Stream::takeWhile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate-) with predicate that rejects nulls. As `Queue::poll` will return `null` when queue is empty - the resulting `Stream` will contain elements from the queue in their order (this is alternative to using `limit` as described in the first solution) :

```
@Override
public Stream<T> stream() {
    return Stream.generate(queue::poll)
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
}
```

Comment: *Beware*. `Stream.generate` creates an *unordered* stream which entirely defeats the purpose of iterating in priority order. It happens to process the elements in the desired order for sequential streams, but that’s not a guaranteed behavior. Creating a `sorted` stream is a safe solution, which also won’t empty the queue, which is the usual expected behavior when streaming over a collection.