# Java Streams() vs Heap.poll() differences

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, java-stream, heap

While solving a question on Leetcode, I got wrong answer using approach 2 while converting heap elements to a list. Rest of the approach is same.
What is the difference between the two? I used to think both are same.

Question https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-words/

Solution 1:

```
List<String> ans = new ArrayList();
while (!heap.isEmpty()) ans.add(heap.poll());
```

Solution 2:

```
List<String> ans = heap.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Complete Code: https://editor.mergely.com/FhTbQDIg/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize PriorityQueue.stream().foreach to iterate in priority order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349022/how-to-customize-priorityqueue-stream-foreach-to-iterate-in-priority-order)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator()). When you are streaming directly, it uses the `iterator()` method and hence order wont be maintained.

You can change your line to

```
List<String> ans = Stream.generate(heap::poll)
  .limit(heap.size())
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```